# Using offset function with If function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

```
If((address(row(),column()-17)) ="cob1",1,2)
```

Am trying to check if value is 'COB' in column A ,then put value 1 in column 17.

Can anyone help? How do I use offset with this?

Comment: Is this a formula or VBA code?

Comment: I want to use in my vba code to set it for all rows in column 17.vba code it is.I am looking for correct formula though.

Comment: You should pick one or the other. There's no use in using formulas and VBA at the same time, unless there is no other easy way. In this instance, it is by far the best to do one or the other.

Comment: Can you add some more VBA code and include the place where the `if` statement would go. There are many ways to reference cells and it would be counterproductive to show you an example using a different convention. (read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You posted a formula for excel.  a VBA statement would look like this:

```
If cells(row(1),column(2)) = "cob1" then cells(row(1),column(3)).value = 1 : cells(row(1),column(3)).value = 2
```

Comment: I want a formula in excel so I can use it for all cells in column using formulaR1C1 property

Answer (score 0):

may be you're after something like:

```
Range("Q1:Q100").FormulaR1C1 = "=If(RC1=""cob1"", 1,2)" '<-- this checks for column "A" value in the same row
```

or

```
Range("Q1:Q100").FormulaR1C1 = "=If(RC[-16]=""cob1"", 1,2)" '<-- this checks for 16 column to the left value in the same row
```

Comment: Ya this only, but the formula doesn't populate my column :(

Comment: without any example of a "before" and "after" scenarios is hard to tune the answer

Comment: Cob1 is in column 1, and I need to put the value in column 17 as 1 if it's cob1 and 2 if it's cob2.

Comment: sorry, it was a copy/paste error. I'm sure you already guessed the "final cut". Anyhow see edited answer

Comment: @Sunaina did you get through it?

Comment: Yes @user3598756 :)